# How to import other libraries in mit scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

This is a newbie question about how to load dependencies in mit scheme

for example, I wish to use the streams library defined here.
http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html

```
(library (streams primitive)
  (export stream-null stream-cons stream? stream-null? stream-pair?
          stream-car stream-cdr stream-lambda)

 .....
 .....)
```

what do I do? is it already there because it is a srfi? do I save it as a file? how do I call these functions?

Comment: Most of those functions are in mit-scheme except for stream-lambda and stream? and stream-cons is called cons-stream.

Comment: @WarwickMasson While that is true, MIT Scheme's built-in streams work on a totally different model from SRFI 41's streams. There are legitimate reasons to want to prefer SRFI 41 streams. (Disclosure: I ported SRFI 41 streams to Guile, despite the existence of a built-in streams library in Guile.)

Comment: (Interestingly, from the feedback I received for my Guile port of SRFI 41, the single improvement that people are most happy with is that I changed `stream->list` from right-fold to left-fold, so people don't get a stack overflow when they're converting long streams.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRFI 41's reference implementation has two variants, [one for R5RS](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/r5rs.ss) and one for R6RS. MIT Scheme is boycotting R6RS, so you should use the R5RS version.

I haven't used MIT Scheme, so I can't say further beyond that. From what I see on their home page, MIT Scheme also appears not to have a module system, so you probably need to just save that file to your project directory and `load` it in, the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say that using `,(import (srfi 133))` has worked for me when I needed `vector-fold`